# Looping through returned mongo collection not able to add new value to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm returning a Mongo collection (using Mongoose) with my node application and am trying to loop through it when its returned to augment a new value to each collection item.

I'm using underscore's each, but for some reason it's not appending what I'm adding to the list. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
Submission.find({}).sort('date', -1).execFind(function (err, submissions) {

    _.each(submissions, function (submission, key) {
        submissions[key]['newValue'] = 'test';
    });
});
```

But it's not adding in newValue : 'test'.

When I console.log it, I get this:

```
[{
    user_id: 1234,
    title: 'testing tyhe slug generation',
    description: '',
    topic: 'movies',
    source: 'http://www.apple.com',
    ip: '127.0.0.1',
    approved: false,
    slug: 'testing-tyhe slug generation',
    _id: 5133a60e16661e41db000001,
    created: Sun Mar 03 2013 11:35:42 GMT-0800 (PST),
    thumbnail: '9146edb190a960c1cc3b0eda7d9f719d'
}, {
    user_id: 1234,
    title: 'New submission test slug',
    description: '',
    topic: 'food-drink',
    source: 'http://www.apple.com',
    ip: '127.0.0.1',
    approved: false,
    slug: 'new-submission-test-slug',
    _id: 5133a6c8adcde860db000001,
    created: Sun Mar 03 2013 11:38:48 GMT-0800 (PST),
    thumbnail: 'd80003cf9c81a4982fbb81c99abb52dc'
}]
```

Is this an async issue?

Comment: you must either add it to your schema or convert it to an object before adding some values, afaik you can't just add a value to a mongoose model.. i haven't used the latest versions but i don't think thats possible in v3.x

Comment: In Node, for each is async. I'm not sure whether this is the case with underscore, but if `each` in underscore is also async, you need to wait for all the calls to finish before using the new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bob_cobb, Mongoose return the result as a collection of "documents". I mean an array of javascript objects not a JSON. So any careless operation done in these documents also affect database content.

Here As per my understanding,  you want to add dynamic or added attribute in documents. So do as follows,

```
Submission.find({}).sort('date', -1).execFind(function (err, submissions) {

    _.each(submissions, function (submission, key) {
        //Here you are converting javascript object into JSON. 
        //That is remove all the functions associated with "submission" object.
        submissions[key] = submissions[key].toJSON(); 
        submissions[key]['newValue'] = 'test';

        //Note: Here submission.save() won't work.
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh, weird. Yeah this will work perfect because I'm passing this back to my controller to be sent to my view. Thanks for the explanation, hilarudeens. Works perfectly.